# Prove the unicity of the differential of a function.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the unicity of the differential of a function.

Suppose we have two differential $d_1f_x\not=d_2f_x$ such that

$\lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})-d_1f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=\lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})-d_2f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=0$

Then,

$\lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})-d_1f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}-\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})-d_2f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=\lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow \bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})-d_1f_x(\bar{h})||-||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})-d_2f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}\leq \lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow \bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})||+||d_1f_x(\bar{h})||-||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})||-||d_2f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=\lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow \bar{0}}\frac{||d_1f_x(\bar{h})||-||d_2f_x(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=0$

Im this step i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. 
$$ \| d_1 f_x (h) - d_2 f_x (h) \| ≤ \|h\|\left( \left\|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - d_1f_x (h)}{\|h\|}\right\|+ \left\|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - d_2f_x (h)}{\|h\|}\right\|\right)$$

Which means that if $v$ is a unit vector, $d_1 f_x (v) = d_2 f_x (v)$. Use a basis $v_1\dots v_n$ to conclude that the columns of the matrix form of $d_1f_x$, $d_2f_x$ in this basis are the same.